# Trouble validating textField in iOS

Tags: ios, validation, textfield

I have to validate all fields before sending the data to the mySQL table in an iOS app I'm developing. (there cannot be empty fields).

The code I've written is below.

What happens is: when I press the SEND button while running the app, it sends the data first, then it shows the dialog informing that the fields cannot be empty. I don't understand why! Can someone please help me?

```
- (IBAction)send:(id)sender {

if( ([dia.text isEqualToString:@""]) || ([nome.text isEqualToString:@""]) || ([local.text isEqualToString:@""]) || ([endereco.text isEqualToString:@""]) || ([horario.text isEqualToString:@""]) || ([informacoes.text isEqualToString:@""]) || ([telefone.text isEqualToString:@""]))
{

    UIAlertView *ErrorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Erro!!"
                                                         message:@"Preencha todos os campos!" delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [ErrorAlert show];

}


NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dia=%@&nome=%@&local=%@&endereco=%@&horario=%@&informacoes=%@&telefone=%@", dia.text, nome.text, local.text, endereco.text, horario.text, informacoes.text, telefone.text];
const char *urlUTF8 = [post UTF8String];
NSString *postBody = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:urlUTF8];
NSData *postData = [postBody dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postDataLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://url_goes_here"]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postDataLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *returnData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];
NSLog(@"****** RESPOSTA: %@", content);


UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Anuncio enviado"
                                                message:@"Agora seu anuncio será submetido a moderação, e se aprovado será publicado."
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

}

Comment: All of the code from `NSString *post...` onwards should be in an `else` clause. You only want to execute that if there wasn't an error in the field. Your current code shows an alert but sends the data anyway

Comment: Paulw11 has right, you should put the alert in an else clause, or call a return after the showing ErrorAlert.

Comment: Either put return statement in IF{} condition or write all the code after if condition in Else{}

Comment: Thanks! it worked!